# Can’t import a module in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a Meteor app I want to have a secret code that runs on the server and being called by the client so I want to have a Meteor.method that runs on the client side but execute part of its code on the server side (API calls)

I can’t import a server module in lib or shared folder
Similar to this example in the documentation

https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#secret-code

imports > server > apicalls.js

```
export const apicall = function () {}
 // Here I want to make my API calls on the server side
```

shared > methods.js

```
import {apicall} from "../imports/server/apicalls.js"; 
//I want to import the apicall function in a method to run it in the client side
```

I get error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ‘…/imports/server/apicalls.js’
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to your file in "shared > methods.js" attempted to be compiled by Meteor build for Client as well, but as expected, the build prevents your file in "imports > server > apicalls.js" from being available for Client build.

That is why Meteor provides you with `Meteor.call("myMethodName")` syntax Client side: you just provide a "magic" string, you do not have to actually import the Method code content on Client. But make sure it is declared on Server with `Meteor.methods({ "myMethodName": function() {} })` so that the Server knows what to do.